# Transform grammar to avoid common prefixes

Tags: javacc

I have this grammar with common prefixes (`<id>`) and I want to transform it to avoid them.

```
void Components() : {}
{
    (Read() | Write())* (<id>Assignment())* <id>Declaration() (Read() | Write() | <id>(Assignment() | Declaration()))*
}
```

The problem is `(<id>Assignment())* <id>Declaration()`. The grammar can have 0 or more Assignments/Read/Write statments but at least 1 Declaration and then any statment/declaration in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring this is easy, but I probably wouldn't do it.  I'd probably look ahead a little further.  Here are two solutions

---

**Factor out the `<id>`**

```
void Components() : {}
{
    (Read() | Write())*
    <id>
    (Assignment() <id>)*
    Declaration()
    ( Read()
    | Write()
    | <id> (Assignment() | Declaration())
    )*
}
```

---

**Use longer lookahead**

```
void Components() : {}
{
    (Read() | Write())*
    (LOOKAHEAD( 2 ) <id> Assignment())*
    <id> Declaration()
    ( Read()
    | Write()
    | LOOKAHEAD( 2 ) <id> Assignment()
    | <id> Declaration())
    )*
}
```